# Cohanim in Auschwitz

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, cemetery-grave, holocaust-shoah

A lot of people died in Auschwitz, and since cohanim are [not allowed](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9922#v=1) to become tamei (ritually impure) by touching a corpse, may cohanim enter Auschwitz?

Comment: Hello Lior, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I think this is a great question, thanks for posting! One thing you might want to keep in mind is that this site is **not** for practical halachic advice -- treat information you get from here like something you heard [from a crowd of you friends](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and consult a rabbi for a final ruling. Hope to see you around the site!

Comment: You might want to look at our other ~130 [tag:kohen-priest] questions -- you might find something interesting there. Enjoy!

Comment: You you really have to check out the article towards the end of _Mincha Tehora_ by R Daniel Wolf. He goes through the sources and addresses the current situation at different camps/cemeteries/forests etc. EDIT: link http://etzion.org.il/he/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%94-%D7%98%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-22-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94

Comment: Your question was closed as "off-topic," because, as written, it sought practical halachic advice. I took the liberty of depersonalizing your question so that it could be reopened, which it was. Please remember to consult a rabbi when necessary. If my edit was incorrect then by all means fix it [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/47305/edit).

Comment: (I hope you have a meaningful trip!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Chayim K'halacha question 223](http://www.heichal.co.il/products/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94/1681) - [Rabbi Boruch Shlomo Blizinsky](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/question.php?id=692) - says a Kohain may go on the paths that lead to Auschwitz however may not enter the area where the incinerators are.

Comment: The link goes only to the home page. Can you update it so that it goes to the page having the answer? This is an interesting halachic point. Cremation is not allowed in Jewish law. If a Jew cremates himself, and they bury the ashes somewhere, is he considered "dead", halachically as far as Cohanim entering that area? Or was some exception made for Holocaust victims who were cremated against their will?

Comment: @DanF The sefer is not available online any longer.