# Kohanim in Eastern Europe

Tags: kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, cemetery-grave, holocaust-shoah

Another question on this website deals with the issue of [kohanim in Auschwitz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47305/cohanim-in-auschwitz). To be "strict", a kohen today could simply avoid going to death camps altogether. Elsewhere, however, is not so easy. Are there published teshuvot that address the problems for kohanim of going walking through forests and fields in Poland, Ukraine, Belarus and the Baltic states? Sadly, many of these locations are the sites of mass graves, a great deal of which are unmarked and most of which contain the remains of dead Jews.

I am not a kohen and I am not asking for a psak. I just want to know if there are published teshuvot that speak of this issue, and what kohanim residing in these places do in order to avoid it. My guess is that in most places it's a *safek sfeika* (*safek* that the site is a mass grave, plus the additional *safek* that the people murdered there were Jewish), but in some places those *sfeikot* collapse into reasonable certainty.

So, for example, while a kohen might not be able to visit Babi Yar, Ponary, Serniki and other such places, does that mean that they also cannot wander through the woods and fields in their environs?

Comment: Re "_safek sfeika_ (_safek_ that the site is a mass grave, plus the additional _safek_ that the people murdered there were Jewish)": that doesn't look like a _s'fek s'feka_ to me: you can't turn it around: "maybe the people in the grave aren't Jews and, even if they are, maybe it's not a grave" doesn't work.

Comment: @msh210 - really? I'm not aware that a sfek sfeka needs to be reversible in that way - do you have a source for that?? (Sorry to ask a question under a question, but this also changes my reading of Taharot in the Mishna. Are you sure?)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if this was true, there would be no end. I would think that all of Europe and Eretz Yisrael has the status of a safek for  Jews having being murdered there. Not just the Shoah - add pogroms, inquisitions, crusades, and expulsions going back to the first Temple being destroyed :(.

Comment: @Miriam Eretz Yisroel has a chezkas Kashrus... Don't have a source for that, but it's what I have heard while discussing. I live here. There are places which are very questionable. For example I know of Kohanim that wouldn't step foot into Teveriya as it is rumored that all parts of the city today (not the old city) might have been a cemetery at one point or another. Another problematic city is Tzfas. It is said that the Arizal purified Eretz Yisroel by marking all scattered graves. (He is the source for the locations of all the known tanaims graves)

Comment: No, I don't, sorry.

Comment: An additional problem is Bet Hapras, a rabbinical problem. I think that the Gemara and Mishnayot in nazir and (I forgot) has rules of shchunat Kvarot and such things. Before all if nobody has found a death in the site, we do not be afraid.

Comment: @ShimonbM msh210 is referring to a rule called Sefek Sefeka HaMitHapech ספק ספקא המתהפך It is referenced on wikipedia https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A7_(%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94)#.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.A7_.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.99.D7.A7.D7.90 and you can find more on google.

Comment: @DoubleAA, thanks, I couldn't think of the term. ShimonbM, http://etzion.org.il/vbm/archive/yomyom/r/r12.php is a short, well-written post on the logic, though it doesn't mention the _shitos l'halacha_. We should continue this in [chat] if at all.