# Kohen visiting concentration camp

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, kohen-priest

Looking for a book/resource to learn about  kohanim visiting concentration camps in Germany. Any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodea!

Comment: Check out http://etzion.org.il/he/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%94-%D7%98%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-22-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47305/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73794/759